# Prometheus verify if a deployment exist

Tags: prometheus

I need to know if a deployment/pod exists and it's in running state from a list of deploy, for example, if I have 3 deployments (app1, app2 and app3) I want to verify if this deployment exist. It is possible? I use kube-state-metrics to expose more Kubernetes metrics

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [absent()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#absent) function exists for this purpose:

```
# Both namespace and deployment name are mandatory to obtain a precise trigger.
absent(kube_deployment_created{namespace="foo", deployment="bar"})
```

`kube_deployment_created` is a metric that shows when the deployment has been created. It will disappear when you delete the deployment, thus triggering an alert.

**Although,** this might be not the best way to handle things. If the deployment produces a certain metric, you might track its absence instead. To better understand what I mean, read Rob Ewaschuk's great article: [My Philosophy on Alerting](https://docs.google.com/document/d/199PqyG3UsyXlwieHaqbGiWVa8eMWi8zzAn0YfcApr8Q/edit#)